# Drools 7.4.1 : How to get a list of rules not matched from excel

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

Drools can return list of rules matched using below code but can it return ruleset in which no rules were matched or a list of rules not matched? If yes, how? In code, i want to know if no rules matched or executed in a particular ruleset.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.kie.api.event.rule.AfterMatchFiredEvent;
    import org.kie.api.event.rule.DefaultAgendaEventListener;
    import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.Match;

     /**
     * Wrapper to log matched rules for input request.
     *
     */
     public class DroolsResponseReader extends DefaultAgendaEventListener {

private List<Match> matchList = new ArrayList<Match>();

boolean isRuleFired() {
    return matchList.size() > 0;
}

@Override
public void afterMatchFired(final AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
    matchList.add(event.getMatch());
}

public String rulesFiredToString() {
    if(matchList.size() == 0) {
        return "No Rule Fired!";
    } else {
        StringBuilder matches = new StringBuilder("Rule Fired : ");
        for (Match match : matchList) {
            matches.append("\nRule: ").append(match.getRule().getName());
        }
        return matches.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get the answer for the same ??